# What is the corresponding androix library for com.android.support:support-compat?

Tags: android, androidx

What is the corresponding `androidx` library for `com.android.support:support-compat` to implement `push notifications`?

They say [here](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification?hl=en) that it is part of androidx but as usual the documentation fails to provide the right directions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core:$core_version'
```

Use the library above in your code. Android provides a list of changes in libraries in case you need to check in future [link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings)

Answer (score 4):

For Java use - implementation "androidx.core:core:$core_version"

For Kotlin use - implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:$core_version"

Answer (score 1):

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'

[Refactoring using Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qEfA.png)